# lodash / underscore.js function to create array consisting of n copies of x

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

<s>*I suspect the reason I am asking this question is the fact that my vocabulary lacks a better term for the function I am looking for and thus I am failing to locate it on google and the lodash API documentation.*</s>

Do `underscore` and `lodash` provide a dedicated function that generates an array by simply pushing the (return) value of `x` to an empty array `n` times where `x` is either a value or a generator function?

I could think of numerous use cases for such a function and even though the functionality is easily replicated with a simple `for`-loop, functions provided by utility libraries such as `underscore` and `lodash` usually are and their purpose is often to provide the optimal implementation.

Turns out the `_.times` **nearly** provides the functionality I am looking for; as described in the official API documentation:

```
_.times(n, [iteratee=_.identity], [thisArg]) 

// Invokes the iteratee function n times, returning an array of the results of each invocation. The iteratee is bound to thisArg and invoked with one argument; (index).
```

This obviously does not let me pass in a static value, though.

Comment: `_.fill()` is what you're looking for.

Comment: @Pointy I am not sure it is, as `_.fill` will not accept a generator function as far as I'm concerned and furthermore it will not fill an empty array.

`_.fill([], 'bar', 0, 10); //=> []`
`_.fill(['foo', 'foo'], 'bar', 0, 10); //=> ['bar', 'bar']`

Comment: @cookiemonster So use loop

Comment: OK how about `_.times()`?

Comment: @hindmost as I pointed out in my question, most `underscore.js` / `lodash` functions are implementations of simple loops, which is why I expected there would be a dedicated function for this

Comment: A non-function parameter value should be allowed too, imo

Comment: @cookiemonster Are you looking to call the generator function separately for each element of the new array, or just call it once and assign that value to each element? Your question is ambiguous in that regard.

Comment: @JLRishe I meant the former option in that regard (so separately)

Comment: `_.times` is very close to what I was looking for but still does not accept a static value. Thanks a lot either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>Not a dedicated function, but perhaps this would suffice?:</s>

<s>*.map(*.range(n), x)</s>

**Edit:** As Pointy has suggested, `_.times()` will do what you are describing if `x` is a generator:

```
_.times(n, x)
```

`_.times` will ignore `x` if it's not a function, so you may need to use a mixin for your uses:

```
_.mixin({ 
    generate: function (length, x) { 
        return _.times(length, _.isFunction(x) ? x : _.constant(x));
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, this seems to be the most elegant solution. Would you reckon the lodash devs would consider adding this to the lodash core if I added an (enhancement) issue or created a pull request?

Comment: @cookiemonster I have very little knowledge of what the lodash devs would consider a worthwhile addition to the library. I do know that as one example they're [not a fan of `flatMap`](https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/issues/452#issuecomment-45321298) (which seems like a fundamental operation to me), and I'm guessing that if they were going to implement a version of `_.times` that repeated a value, they would have done so already.

Comment: FYI, `flatMap` was added into *lodash* core, as of [v4.0.0](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/Changelog#v400).